# Clear custom font setting from a Word style

Tags: microsoft-word

Microsoft Word lets me specify a font name, size, or basically any other setting for styles. Most of these settings are empty for new styles, i. e. they inherit the setting from the parent style.

As soon as you enter something in one of those fields, it's there. Create a new style and set it to use a different font.

Now, how can I clear that setting and reset the style to inherit the values for that font name, size or whatever? When I try and make the input field empty, the previous value just appears again. I cannot restore that initial style that any new style has. The only way I know is undoing the change (if still possible) or recreating the entire document and all styles within it (which is obviously not practical most of the time).

Answer (score 1):

When modifying a style (character style), instead of clearing font/font size directly in a style window, click **Format** in the left bottom corner, choose **Font** and clear appropriate values in the window that appears.

Comment: If I do that, nothing changes. When I confirm everything, the previous font is still in place. When I reopen the Font dialog, the font is there again. (Word 2016)

Comment: I use Word 2010. Clearing font name for a style only works for me for character styles and only when the style is based on default paragraph font. However in other cases changing font name to parent font name makes the font in the inherited style behave like inherited, e.g. a new change in font in the parent style is inherited by a child style.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new custom style in Word and apply it to the selected text, you can try the following steps as a workaround to revert to original parent style:

1. Select the text, then the applied custom Style will be displayed in **Styles** window in **Home** tab.
2. Right-click the custom style, select **Modify**. [image]
3. Check the **Style based on** parent style[image]
4. Cancel the Modify Style window, select the original based on style to apply it for selected text.